# Double-tap 'search everywhere' feature has stopped working

Tags: ide, editor, phpstorm

I am using PHPStorm 7.1 and suddenly overnight the 'double-tap' feature that quickly pops up a box to search anywhere has just stopped working - can anyone suggest how I can possibly fix this without re-installing the software?

It is a work machine so I'm prefer to not have to reinstall it if possible

Comment: 1) `Settings | Keymap` -- look for "Search Everywhere" -- see what keys it has assigned (should be none). See if assigning custom shortcut will work. 2) Possibly you have selected different keymap where default shortcut (Shift 2 times) is reserved to another action? 3) Any plugins updated recently?

Comment: Weird... for some reason my machine seems to have version 7.0 & 7.1 installed - I run the 'Invalidates Cache' feature in 7.0 then re-opened in 7.1 and it now works fine

Thanks for the quick response though - you answer taught me a few things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File > Invalid Caches / Restart > Invalidate and Restart..

This seems to work for me